# Possible UITableViewCell UILabel Compositing Anomaly

Tags: iphone, uikit, uitableview, gradient

Consider a **UITableViewCell** with a style of **UITableViewCellStyleDefault**, set in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, and a gradient background, set in `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`.

When this is rendered, the `textLabel` will blend in just fine with the gradient, and highlighting works just as well.

Now, what if we keep everything identical, but change the cell style to **UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle**? In my case, the `textLabel` and `detailTextLabel` no longer blend at all! They take on ... some other color. Not too far off from the colors in the gradient, but it simply doesn't blend. Change the style back to default, and all is well.

Now, I realize I could set the labels to `clearColor` in `...willDisplayCell...` but I've been told over and over again, "Don't do that! Leave them colors alone."

Perhaps I have to do that as a workaround? Or might something else be amiss? Clues welcome/appreciated!

Comment: Where have you read / been told to not change the label colors to clear? I've done that in a few places...

Comment: IIRC I've heard this time and again from Apple devs at WWDC presos, among other places. As they say, when using "Color Blended Layers" in the Core Anamation Instrument with a tethered iOS device, "green is good" - keep compositing to a minimum and all that. Even with a gradient background, for UITableViewCellStyleDefault and an otherwise untouched textLabel, it's green all the way. I suspect UITableViewCell is helping out with the drawing in that case ... but it doesn't seem to help when using the Subtitle style. So I'm wondering if that disconnect is a bug, a feature, or something in between.

Answer (score 0):

A work around would be to use NSString's drawInRect function. You could use the NSString sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode: method to calculate the rect size and then draw the strings out that way.

more about string sizes and drawing here on [apples docs site](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Indeed! I do use drawInRect whenever I use drawRect, but in this case the goal was to keep outta there and stick with the stock table view cell bits. (For exercise purposes only, mind you!)